# Displaying Last 2 Results from Database Query

Tags: php, xhtml, blogs

So I've been working on the code below and, no matter what I do it won't display more than the current database *=(From the URL http://www.example.com/blogs/1)

I would like it to display the last two or however many I put int he top argument.

I've tried switching "story id from Blogs" with "* from blogs" both work, but neither does what I'm trying to do. I have two blog entries and it only ever returns blog entry 1.

```
<?php

$sql2="select top 2 storyid from Blogs order by storyid desc";  

//echo "$sql<br/>"; 

$results2=mysql_query($sql,$connection); 

while ($result=mysql_fetch_assoc($results2)){ 

     $title=$result["Title"];  

     $storyid=$result["storyid"];

     $photo2=$result["Photo2"];

     $date=$result["Date"];

     ?>




                      <li>

<img src="/images/<?php echo $photo2; ?>" alt="Blog link" />

                          <div class="blog-details">

     <h4><a href="/blogs/<?php echo "$storyid"; ?>"><?php echo "$title"; ?></a></h4>

     <p><?php print date('M d Y', strtotime($date)); ?> - <a href="#">2 Comments</a></p>

<li>

<img src="/images/<?php echo $photo2; ?>" alt="Blog link" />

                          <div class="blog-details">

     <h4><a href="/blogs/<?php echo "$storyid"; ?>"><?php echo "$title"; ?></a></h4>

     <p><?php print date('M d Y', strtotime($date)); ?> - <a href="#">2 Comments</a></p>

     <?php

}

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try modifying your query to use limit instead of top

```
SELECT storyid FROM Blogs ORDER BY storyid DESC LIMIT 0,2
```

Comment: It worked! Let me explain... I had to use "Select * FROM Blogs and then Limit 0,2 AND i had to get rid of the extra LI because it was rendering a December 31 1969." Once I did that it's now working fine!

Comment: If I had one more reputation I could actually vote you up! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

For MySQL you have to use LIMIT instead of TOP. See if that works.